# Wordpress routing to specific functions

Tags: php, function, routes, wordpress

I have a class and I would like to call a specific function from that class when a button is pressed. I typically use laravel framework in development and I have not used wordpress so far.
In laravel I have a file named routes.php and there I route the functions like this:
`Route::method('url','controller@function');`. Is it possible to do this in wordpress? if yes, how do I define the routes, and if not, what alternative would you suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that this is possible in wordpress at current; however I have found this useful in the past http://ruslanbes.com/devblog/2013/04/03/wordpress-routing-explained/

Comment: I have started learning wordpress.. some concepts are quite weird and it looks like spaghetti coding for me.. everything is so spread everywhere and it looks like the theme is actually an application which makes no sense.. no separation of concerns..etc.. looks like hell to maintain